# Merging/adding synonyms for tags only differing by dots and dashes

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I've created a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81926/find-tags-differing-by-dots-and-dashes-only-with-no-synonym) in [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com) to list all tags that match a tag when removing all dots and dashes. This looks to have brought up quite a few possible candidates for merging or adding synonyms.

What's the procedure for this?
Should people just pick one / a few, look into them then submit a request each time?

```
SELECT Tags.TagName AS NoDotDashTagName,
       Tags.Count AS NoDotDashTagCount,
       Tags2.TagName AS DotDashTagName,
       Tags2.Count AS DotDashTagCount
FROM Tags
CROSS JOIN Tags AS Tags2
WHERE Tags.TagName <> Tags2.TagName AND
      (REPLACE(REPLACE(Tags2.TagName, '.', ''), '-', '') = Tags.TagName) AND

      NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM TagSynonyms
                 WHERE (SourceTagName = Tags.TagName AND
                        TargetTagName = Tags2.TagName) OR
                       (TargetTagName = Tags.TagName AND
                        SourceTagName = Tags2.TagName)
                )
                
ORDER BY Tags.TagName
```

---

For reference, here are some results:

```
NoDotDashTagName     NoDotDashTagCount DotDashTagName        DotDashTagCount 
-------------------- ----------------- --------------------- --------------- 
activeobjects        9                 active-objects        3               
activerelation       11                active-relation       30              
activesupport        137               active-support        5               
addressbar           43                address-bar           19              
adhoc                226               ad-hoc                70              
alwaysontop          9                 always-on-top         33              
antialiasing         264               anti-aliasing         30              
appcode              15                app-code              64              
appdata              62                app-data              32              
applicationdomain    32                application-domain    11              
applicationsettings  28                application-settings  267             
applicationstate     7                 application-state     27              
authorizeattribute   16                authorize-attribute   48              
autoincrement        176               auto-increment        515             
autoindent           17                auto-indent           48              
autoupdate           61                auto-update           267             
autoversioning       14                auto-versioning       8
```

Comment: There is another comprehensive list maintained in [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags) post. You may add new tags there if you like.