# Merge tags [requirejs] and [require.js]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Both tags refer to the same JavaScript library; [require.js](/questions/tagged/require.js) (26 questions, 6 followers) should be made a synonym of [requirejs](/questions/tagged/requirejs) (2000+ questions, 450+ followers).

Comment: Are there any other examples of unmerged *xxx.yy* and *xxxyy* ?

Comment: @hyde: not sure, but there's `handlebars.js` and `handlebars`.

Comment: @hyde see this [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/144594/find-tags-that-only-differ-by-a)

Comment: @rene this is also interesting: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/144601/find-tags-that-only-differ-for-instead-of

Comment: Or [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149738/merging-adding-synonyms-for-tags-only-differing-by-dots-and-dashes)